# Define a function with singular Taylor expansion

Tags: function-construction, series-expansion

With an undefined symbol `f` command

```
Series[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

returns

```
f[0]+f'[0] x+O[x]^2
```

Can I introduce a first order pole, without any other assumptions? i.e. I want to get

```
r/x+f[0]+f'[0] x+O[x]^2
```

with a specified constant `r`.

Comment: Series[r/x + f[x], {x, 0, 1}]?

Comment: @FredSimons Well, I want formulas to look compact and the term `r/x` to only appear when a series expansion is made.

Comment: So `f` is not quite undefined; it must have the property that it has a pole of order 1 at `x=0`. The most compact form I can think of is my first comment, or `Series[f[x]/x, {x, 0, 1}]`.

Comment: Say I'm working with polynomials of `f[x]` and `x`, i.e. consider expressions of the type `f[x]^3-x^2`. I want these formal expressions to stay as they are, until I decide to make a series expansion `Series[f[x]^3x^2-3f[x]/x, {x,0,1}]`, then the expansion of `f[x]` must start not with a constant term but with a pole. Of course I can always make a substitution `f[x]->r/x+g[x]` and expand then, but I thought that there could be a more convenient way to do this. After all, having a pole is a property of the function `f`, so I would like to be able to specify it.

Comment: It is still not clear to me what you are asking. When there is a pole, the series expansion will show the pole. A test for a pole of order one at `x=0` could be `lim x f[x] != 0` for `x->0`, if you do not want to use a series expansion.